# Cumber red ki, is his regular ki or is it a transformation?

Tags: dragon-ball-heroes

In Dragon Ball, all saiyans have white/transparent ki with the exception of Vegita in a few chapters of Dragon Ball Z where he had light blue ki, and Goku Black who had black/violet/transparent ki before transforming into super saiyan Rose. What is Cumber red ki about then?  is Cumber red ki his regular ki or is it a transformation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dark Aura which surrounds Kanba here is just his ordinary ki which is supposedly considered to be a dark evil Ki. if you look at the *Dragon Ball Heroes Universe Mission 3* [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJBVE_9tzao), you can see Kanba as a Regular Super Saiyan at the 0:09-0:10 second mark.

Hence it is fair to assume that is Kanba's ki in his Base form. I have also attached an image of the same below.

[image: Super Saiyan Kanba]

Comment: If in base form he is as strong as super saiyan blue vegito, in super saiyan he might be the strongest character in all Dragon Ball Heroes